# I can't get a queryset from GenericForeignKey

Tags: python, django

How to fix this error

`FieldError at /movies/ Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.`

This is a class for getting user activity by queryset

```
from typing import Dict, Any
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from specifications.serializers import ActivitySerializer


class UserActivity(object):

    def __init__(self, user) -> None:
        
        self.user = user
        
    def get_activity(self, model: ModelBase, query: QuerySet) -> Dict[str, Any]|None:
        
        if model._meta.model_name == "comment":
            objects = model.objects.filter(user=self.user, comment__in=query)
            serializer = ActivitySerializer(objects, many=True)
            
        else:
            objects = model.objects.filter(
                user=self.user,
                content_object__in=query
                )
            
            serializer = ActivitySerializer(objects, many=True)
        
        return serializer.data
```

I have a view for getting `movies`

```
class MovieListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()

        paginator = PageNumberPagination()
        paginator.page_size = 10
        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(movies, request)
        serializer = MovieListSerializer(page, many=True)
        user_activity = UserActivity(request.user)
        
        data = {
            "movies": serializer.data,
        }
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_activity = UserActivity(request.user)
            
            activity = {
                "user": {
                    "ratings": user_activity.get_activity(Rating, page),
                    "watchlist": user_activity.get_activity(WatchList, page)
                }
            }
            
            data.update(activity)

        response = Response(data)
        response['X-Total-Count'] = paginator.page.paginator.count
        response['X-Page-Size'] = paginator.page_size
        response['X-Page'] = paginator.page.number

        return response
```

I have 2 models (`movie`, `rating`)

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating)
    watchlist = GenericRelation(WatchList)

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_ratings')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={"model__in": ('show', 'movie', 'episode')})
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

`content_object` is not a proper field in the model (is a Django ORM construct) so you cannot `filter`/`exclude` using it. You have to filter on `content_type`

```
    objects = model.objects.filter(
        user=self.user,
        content_type__in=query
        )
```

Comment: but when i use content_type or object_id queryset returns empty

Comment: I have this record :
user=1, content_type=20, object_id=1
when i put this exact value even in orm it returns empty